# Checkout Process for Xamarin E commerce application

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm new to development (I'm self Taught I got a job recently as an"app Developer") and this is my first real big project. In essence, it's an e-commerce store that uses a very awkward API. My Checkout process is taking 6 seconds per item and you can imagine if I let a user checkout 50+ items, they will think something's wrong.

I'm going to share my whole checkout process along with a question. What are my bottlenecks? Too many loops to make checks? How do I improve something like this?

A few things to note, I have a variable and a single Product. Sometimes the API returns the Stock Quantity of `null`, which just means that it's unlimited.

```
        private async void Checkout_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new LoadingPopup());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }

            try
            {

                if (FullCart.CartList == null || FullCart.CartList.Count <= 0 || !FullCart.CartList.Any())
                {
                    var yx = await DisplayAlert("Whoops",
                                "Cart seem's to be empty, We cant checkout nothing", "Back to Cart", "Supplier");
                    if (yx)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var masterDetailPage = new Home();
                        masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Suppliers());
                        Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await BeginCheckout();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }

            try
            {
                await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }

        }
```

```
 private async Task BeginCheckout()
        {
            try
            {
                //You cant checkout if your not logged in There are no Guest Checkouts(I can But would rather not)
                if (Users.LoggedIn && _spamClick == false)
                {
                    if (_orderlineitems == null) _orderlineitems = new List<OrderLineItem>();

                    RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://xxxxx/wp-json/wc/v2/",
                    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

                    var wc = new WCObject(rest);

                    await IsInStock();
                    var order = new Order { status = "on-hold", customer_id = Users.CId };
                    foreach (var item in _simpleCartlist)
                        if (_simpleCartlist.Any(i => i.InStock == false))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();

                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
                            }

                        }
                        else if (_simpleCartlist.All(i => i.InStock))
                        {
                            if (item.StockStatus == "instock" || item.StockStatus is string stringValue && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue) || item.StockStatus == null)
                            {
                                var a = Convert.ToInt32(item.ProductQuantity);
                                if (item.VariationId <= 0) item.VariationId = item.PId;
                                if (item.StockQuantity == 0)
                                {
                                    _productBoughtOut = true;
                                    _productnames.Add(item.ProductName);
                                }

                                order.line_items = order.line_items ?? new List<OrderLineItem>();
                                order.line_items.Add(new OrderLineItem
                                { product_id = item.PId, variation_id = item.VariationId, quantity = a });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();

                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    Crashes.TrackError(ex);
                                }

                                var yx = await DisplayAlert("Order Cant be Placed",
                                    $"{item.ProductName} is out of stock",
                                    "Back to Cart", "Home");
                                if (yx)
                                {
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var masterDetailPage = new Home();
                                    masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Home());
                                    Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    if (_productBoughtOut)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
                        }

                        var yx = await DisplayAlert("Order Cant be Placed", $"Not enough stock for {_productnames}",
                            "Back to Cart", "Home");
                        if (yx)
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var masterDetailPage = new Home();
                            masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Home());
                            Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (_simpleCartlist.All(i => i.InStock))
                    {
                        if (FullCart.CartList != null && _spamClick == false || _items.Items != null && _spamClick == false)
                        {
                            _spamClick = true;
                            await wc.Order.Add(order);

                            Preferences.Clear("Cart");
                            Preferences.Remove("Cart");
                            FullCart.CartList.Clear();
                            _items.Items.Clear();
                            var masterDetailPage = new Home();
                            masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Checkedout());
                            Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
                        }

                        _spamClick = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_spamClick)
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Woops", "Your trying to order twice", "Ok");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var y = await DisplayAlert("Woops", "Please Login to check Out", "Login", "Home");
                        if (y)
                        {
                            var masterDetailPage = new Home();
                            masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Login());
                            Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Home());
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }
        }
```

```
private async Task SingleCheck()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var CartItem in _simpleCartlist)
                    if (_currentListItem == CartItem.PId)
                    {
                        if (_singleProduct.stock_quantity == null)
                        {
                            //CartItem.InStock = true;
                            _singleProduct.stock_quantity = 999999;
                        }
                        if (CartItem.ProductQuantity == 0)
                        {
                            CartItem.ErrorMsg = "Item requires a Quantity of atleast 1" + System.Environment.NewLine + "Quantity Cannot be 0!";
                            await DisplayAlert("Oops", "Whe can't checkout nothing See if a products quantity isnt 0", "Ok");
                            return;
                        }
                        if (_singleProduct.stock_quantity == 0 || _singleProduct.stock_status == "outofstock" ||
                            CartItem.ProductQuantity > _singleProduct.stock_quantity)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();

                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
                            }

                            CartItem.InStock = false;
                            var AlertResult = await DisplayAlert("Not Enough Products",
                                $"There is this much Stock left: {_singleProduct.stock_quantity} for {_singleProduct.name}",
                                "Back to Cart", "Keep Shopping");
                            CartItem.ErrorMsg = "Product shortage " + $" There is this much Stock left: {_singleProduct.stock_quantity} for {_singleProduct.name}";
                            if (AlertResult)
                            {
                                CartItem.InStock = false;
                                CartItem.StockQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(_singleProduct.stock_quantity);
                                _items = new ItemList(FullCart.CartList);
                                cartView.BeginRefresh();
                                CartItem.StockStatus = _singleProduct.stock_status;
                                cartView.EndRefresh();
                                return;
                            }

                            var masterDetailPage = new Home();
                            masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Home());
                            Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
                        }
                        else if (_singleProduct.stock_quantity != 0 && _singleProduct.stock_status == "instock" &&
                                 CartItem.ProductQuantity <= _singleProduct.stock_quantity)
                        {
                            CartItem.ErrorMsg = "";
                            CartItem.InStock = true;
                        }
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }
        }
```

```
 private async Task VariableCheck()
        {
            //TODO if your seeing this, Your probably Developing on this now, if you're... Run! Honestly Run...
            try
            {
                foreach (var CartItem in _simpleCartlist)

                    if (_currentListItem == CartItem.PId)
                    {
                        if (_varProduct.stock_quantity == null)
                        {
                            _varProduct.stock_quantity = 999999;
                        }
                        if (CartItem.ProductQuantity == 0)
                        {
                            CartItem.ErrorMsg = "Item requires a Quantity of atleast 1" + System.Environment.NewLine + "Quantity Cannot be 0!";
                            await DisplayAlert("Oops", "Whe can't checkout nothing See if a products quantity isnt 0", "Ok");
                            return;
                        }
                        if (_varProduct.stock_quantity == 0 || _varProduct.stock_status == "outofstock" ||
                            CartItem.ProductQuantity > _varProduct.stock_quantity)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();

                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
                            }

                            CartItem.InStock = false;
                            var AlertResult = await DisplayAlert("Not Enough Products",
                                $"There is this much Stock left: {_varProduct.stock_quantity} for {CartItem.ProductName} {_varProduct.attributes[2].option}",
                                "Back to Cart", "Keep Shopping");
                            CartItem.ErrorMsg = "Not Enough Products" + $"There is this much Stock left: {_varProduct.stock_quantity} for {CartItem.ProductName} {_varProduct.attributes[2].option}";
                            if (AlertResult)
                            {
                                CartItem.InStock = false;
                                CartItem.StockQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(_varProduct.stock_quantity);
                                _items = new ItemList(FullCart.CartList);
                                cartView.BeginRefresh();
                                CartItem.StockStatus = _varProduct.stock_status;
                                cartView.EndRefresh();
                                return;
                            }

                            var masterDetailPage = new Home();
                            masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Home());
                            Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
                        }
                        else if (_varProduct.stock_quantity != 0 && _varProduct.stock_status == "instock" &&
                                 CartItem.ProductQuantity <= _varProduct.stock_quantity)
                        {
                            CartItem.ErrorMsg = "";
                            CartItem.InStock = true;
                        }
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }
        }
```

```
 private readonly List<CartList> _simpleCartlist;
        private int _currentId;
        private int _currentListItem;
        private ItemList _items;
        private List<OrderLineItem> _orderlineitems;
        private bool _productBoughtOut;
        private List<string> _productnames;
        private Product _singleProduct;
        private bool _spamClick;
        private Variation _varProduct;


        private bool _loading;

        public bool loading
        {
            get => _loading;
            set
            {
                if (_loading == value) return;
                _loading = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();

            }
        }


        private bool _running;

        public bool running
        {
            get => _running;
            set
            {
                if (_running == value) return;
                _running = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();

            }
        }
```

The idea with spam-click is to avoid Double orders. 
I can definitely understand the frustration with all my if's. Any suggestions in regards to that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks:

- Why do `FullCart.CartList.Count <= 0 || !FullCart.CartList.Any()`? That's the same check twice.
- Use proper variable names: `var yx` is meaningless.
- Do not hardcode these kind of things: `new RestAPI("http://xxxxx/wp-json/wc/v2/", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");`. API urls etc. should be in config files.
- Do not use magic strings: `"on-hold"` in `var order = new Order { status = "on-hold", customer_id = Users.CId };` should really be an `enum`, or at least a centrally configured `const string`. Same for `item.StockStatus == "instock"` and other such items.
- Why is a single user represented by the object `Users` (as in `Users.LoggedIn` and `Users.CId`)?
- Do not leave out braces around large `foreach` sections etc.
- Where did you learn this: `item.StockStatus is string stringValue && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue) || item.StockStatus == null`? Why use this elaborate way when all you need is `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.StockStatus)`? (And again: `StockStatus` should be an `enum`.)
- Besides the meaningless variable name, what bothers me most about `var a = Convert.ToInt32(item.ProductQuantity);` is that `ProductQuantity` isn't an `int` to begin with.
- `order.line_items`: `line_items` should be Pascalcased. Moreover, property names and variable names etc. should only contain alphanumeric characters (exception: private class-wide variables can have an underscore at the start). Ditto `product_id` etc.
- Please get a native English speaker to spellcheck your messages. They often contain spelling errors and incorrect capitalization (e.g. `"Order Cant be Placed"`, `"Cart seem's to be empty, We cant checkout nothing"`,...). Also, `"Woops"` is not a word I expect to see in a e-commerce application.
- Split your methods into smaller ones. For instance, `BeginCheckout()` is 140 lines and mixes UI logic with business logic. Every call to `Navigation` is wrapped in a `try...catch` block which makes things hard to follow. To me that whole method should be a class of its own.
- Looking at `SingleCheck()` I'm baffled that you halt execution inside a foreach to wait for the user to respond in case of a lack of stock. Why not build a report instead and then bother the user only if one or more items cannot be fulfilled?
- `foreach (var CartItem in _simpleCartlist)`: variables should be camelCased.
- Some of the business logic is just incomprehensible: `if (_varProduct.stock_quantity == null) { _varProduct.stock_quantity = 999999; }` How does that even make sense?
- How does this code even hang together? I don't see where `_currentListItem` is set. I don't see why you should need "6 seconds per item". I don't see calls to the APIs.

---

My main recommendation: split these large methods up into small ones, so the program flow becomes much clearer. Do not constantly bounce between business logic and UI calls.

Comment: Just wanna start and say I really appreciate the input This why id love to have a senior to work under The Double check is redundant dint notice that the quick Var xy are for debugging should get rid of those 1000% agree, So Separate class for API Urls? so isntead of saying = "in stock" I should have a const string thats = to "in stock"? The missing Braces is due to rider going a little nuts I represent the Users as UserS instead of user because I have a list of users i check threw in the login, This sounds dumb from my side typing this ,

Comment: Thank you for showing me the shorthand for isNullorWhite dint know that. The Line_items naming is due to the wrappers naming conventions, Im not sure what its even called ( Extending a wrappers classes so I can use my own classes instead type of thing) Separation of concern for ui and business, Noted. So let the process finish then display a report of "Failure this and this is out of stock" ? instead The stock_quantity being null is the api's way of saying "Unlimited"

Comment: So I set a high value, would  int.maxvalue be better? I dont understand my self it shouldnt take 6 seconds to clear this , The only api calls are  await wc.Order.Add(order);

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't set a max value, you should know the amount of stock. Assuming there are a million items in stock seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: Some Items are produced on site so they can basically make a order of 2 billion if someone wanted that The api returns null for infinity basically I dont know why But its not my api

Comment: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products Check the docs its really silly look at list all products Stock-Q = null is tech unlimited

Answer (score 0):

Too many `try/catch` blocks, and it's redundant and misplaced. For instance `Checkout_clicked` method can be done this way :

```
private async void Checkout_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new LoadingPopup());

        // what is happning here ? 
        // when Cart is NULL OR Does not have any elements OR Count is less than zero ? 
        if (FullCart.CartList == null || FullCart.CartList.Count <= 0 || !FullCart.CartList.Any())
        {
            var yx = await DisplayAlert("Whoops","Cart seem's to be empty, We cant checkout nothing", "Back to Cart", "Supplier");

            if (!yx)
            {
                var masterDetailPage = new Home();
                masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Suppliers());
                Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await BeginCheckout();
        }

        await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
    }
}
```

same thing can applied to the other blocks. This is a must do modification as nested `try/catch` is a bad practice, ugly, and it would impact the performance. So,  it must be avoided.

Secondly, when using `if` statements to validate, don't put your method validation in `else` clause. Take `BeginCheckout` as an example :

```
/*
    Part 1 : Validations 
*/

//You cant checkout if your not logged in There are no Guest Checkouts(I can But would rather not)
if (_spamClick)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Woops", "Your trying to order twice", "Ok");
    return; 
}

if (!Users.LoggedIn)
{
    // User is not logged in it should display this message immediately, and return it back to login screen or give the user the choice to go there     
    await DisplayAlert("Woops", "Please Login to check Out", "Login", "Home");
    return;
}

// this is okay
if (_orderlineitems == null) {  _orderlineitems = new List<OrderLineItem>(); }

// outside the loop since it's not releated to the loop 
if (!_simpleCartlist.Any(i => i.InStock == false) || _productBoughtOut) 
{ 
    await Navigation.PopPopupAsync(); 
    return;
}   

if(FullCart.CartList == null || _items.Items == null) { return; /* what should happen if the cart is null ? */ }


/*
    Part 2 : Process 
*/
foreach (var item in _simpleCartlist)
{   
    //if out of stock
    if (item.StockStatus != "instock" || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.StockStatus)) { continue; } // skip this and go to the next item

    ... //rest of the loop 
    var a = Convert.ToInt32(item.ProductQuantity);
    if (item.VariationId <= 0) item.VariationId = item.PId;
    if (item.StockQuantity == 0)
    {
    _productBoughtOut = true;
    _productnames.Add(item.ProductName);
    }

    order.line_items = order.line_items ?? new List<OrderLineItem>();
    order.line_items.Add(new OrderLineItem
    { product_id = item.PId, variation_id = item.VariationId, quantity = a });  
}

_spamClick = true;
await wc.Order.Add(order);
Preferences.Clear("Cart");
Preferences.Remove("Cart");
FullCart.CartList.Clear();
_items.Items.Clear();
var masterDetailPage = new Home();
masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Checkedout());
Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
```

*FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSE ONLY*

Refactoring the `if` statements, to put the main validations at the top of the code, then go to the process. This way, the code would execute the validation part first, then if it passed this part it would go and execute the process part. This is a common used methodology since it's readable, easy to follow, and also follow the execution workflow.

The main idea is, whenever you see that the if condition would have a long executable logic or will include nested `if`s, you should think of inverting it to make it simpler and extract the actual code outside it. Like the example above.

Also, in the example you will notice that I've used `return;` which is something I don't recommend to be used often in a work environment. But for testing and examples would be okay. The reason for that it would not handle anything, while you should handle every expected condition that happens in your logic to be more maintainable and understandable for other developers.

Another thing, braces exist for a reason. So, try to use them, as it would make things much easier to follow and maintainable. Even in Visual Studio, with braces, you could collapse or expand any part you want in the source.

Comment: I see this makes alot of sense
My only Qeustion is how I Do prevent access to the 

order.add ect If a items out of stock, I'd need them to remove that item before I can Properly place the Order(Without using returns ofcourse, as you mentioned its not something youd recommend in a work environment

Comment: @Azurry this is where dividing the code into small portions would come in handy. For instance, in the example of `BeginCheckout` put part 1 & 2 into methods named them something like `CheckoutValidate()` and `CheckoutProcess()` then in the `BeginCheckout` put the validate first, and make it returns a boolean, if true execute the `CheckoutProcess()` if false, it won't be executed.